# How to create a new array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here's the code,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-xz4c93

How to create a new array?
For example:
The output should be like this. when clicking the submit button

```
"tasks": [
    {
      "id": "HmQiCcZUXbSF",
      "failed": false,
      "remarks": "Ok",
      "task": {
        "id": "1fKBO4w0XHg7H",
        "name": "Task 1",
        "description": "Check oil spill"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1qK7AUzgEbqBH",
      "failed": false,
      "remarks": "Ok",
      "task": {
        "id": "ESOSA6aCrOER",
        "name": "Sample1",
        "description": "Desc1"
      }
    }
  ],
```

The output should be the above.

The output is my output:
[image]

should be similar to the postman

```
{
  "id": "1foNLPYHsSmVv",
  "createdBy": "admin",
  "timeCreated": "2019-12-16 12:47:56",
  "updatedBy": "admin",
  "timeUpdated": "2019-12-16 12:47:56",
  "remarks": "All is fine",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": "w1lPuzJIDouF",
      "failed": false,
      "remarks": "Ok",
      "task": {
        "id": "1fKBO4w0XHg7H",
        "name": "Task 1",
        "description": "Check oil spill"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1foD7MW0rRDdH",
      "failed": false,
      "remarks": "Ok",
      "task": {
        "id": "ESOSA6aCrOER",
        "name": "Sample1",
        "description": "Desc1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What is the issue that you are facing.. What is the expected behavior..

Comment: when clicking the submit button the output is: ```{remark: {…}, status: "", otherRemark: ""}```.. the output should be in the above

Comment: So what you want is that with reactive forms you should get the above output right that should be an array.. And if that is what you are looking for.. you should use FormArray and not FormGroup. See refer https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#array

Comment: @ABC what you have shown as output is not an array but a `object`

Comment: @JoelJoseph the output should be like the above of my output

Answer (score 0):

If you need *task* as the only output, then you could something like this.

```
async saveFormData() {
  const reqObj = {
    tasks: this.taskFormGroup.value.remark.tasks
  }
  console.log(reqObj)
}
```

Comment: what if the item is array

Comment: @ABC which item ..? could u give an example .?

Comment: example from the link i share. there's parent 1 and it has 2 child the output should be the same in the above